# SQL Azure : get data between 2 dates, date as a string

Tags: c#, sql, date, datetime, azure

I'm using C#, MVC 4, SQL Azure.

Background: I'm programming a site with DB that each action of the user on the site will be saved upon my DB as a user activity.

Each row as these columns:

- ID
- Date
- UserID
- Description

Now comes my problem, in my country we write the date like this : `DD/MM/YYYY`

Example : `29/11/2014`.

Weird I know but I need this format.

I tried a thousand methods to `INSERT` date value into my DB (SQL Azure) with different formatting and nothing seems to work, and on top of that Microsoft got there 3 types of Date and its very very confusing, so what I did is just set the date field as a string and I assemble the date like this :

```
string date = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "/" 
+ DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "/" 
+ DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + " " 
+ DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" 
+ DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
```

And now I want to get data with query that use "between" two dates like this :

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Date]
  ,[User]
  ,[Description]
FROM [dbo].[ActivityLog]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN 03/09/2014 AND 04/09/2014;
```

and I get this error :

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3/9/2014 21:3' to data type int.

My date looks like this in the DB:

```
3/9/2014 21:3
```

If someone could guide me trough this...Thank You

This is my code :

```
  public static void UpdateLog(string userName, string description)
  {
        try
        {
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string date =  DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();

            string query = "INSERT INTO ActivityLog VALUES('" + guid + "' , '" + date + "' , '" + userName + "' , '" + description + "')";
            AdoHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I changed my code to this :

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO ActivityLog VALUES('" + guid + "' , '" + DateTime.Now + "' , '" + userName + "' , '" + description + "')";
```

Now when I look in my DB I see this :

```
03-Sep-14
```

exactly like my computer is writing at the bottom right corner (where the tray icons).

But that's a problem because someone else enter the site and on his computer he write the dates differently so he will INSERT the DB different format, what can i do to over come this problem ? UTC ?

Comment: I'd suggest doing some research on cultures and string formatting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Do not convert dates to string. Instead, pass the date as a parameter to the query. Show your code and I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3/9/2014 21:3' to data type int.` what is the datatype of the date field.. the error message is telling you that it expects an int as the date is the date defined as `TimeStamp` in the database

Comment: It will work for your insert: `string date =  DateTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd');`

Comment: The point is that the format you want to see when the date is retrieved from the database or even the format you want your users use when inserting data has nothing to do with the format you have to use when saving it to the database.

Comment: @Caffé i dont understand. i want to save the date in unified format.
i dont want that the dates will be written with the "sep" i want "9".

Comment: @marc_s didnt you see the update of post ? i'm changed it to datetime.

Comment: When persisted to the database, the date format is irrelevant to you. There they are "Date, DateTime, TimeStamp" or things like that and the database will accept it only as parameter or as string in a specific format (in this case, 'yyyy-MM-dd').

You have to format it only when retrieving or after retrieving it to show to your users, and at this moment you choose the exhibition format. You're missing important concepts about database column types, user inputs, view formatting, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't convert dates to string. Instead, you should pass the date as a parameter to the query.

If you really want strings, use the MS SQL Server standard: `YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` (the format you see in a query result is not necessarily the format that the server accepts.

You also will have to inform it between single quotes, like that:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Date]
  ,[User]
  ,[Description]
  FROM [dbo].[ActivityLog]
  WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2014-09-03' AND '2014-09-04';
```

Comment: Caffe delete the answer so that others do not give you `- negative marking`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, guys. I edited it to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `where` clause:

```
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN 03/09/2014 AND 04/09/2014
```

It is failing because `/` is an arithmetic operator called division, so I think this is turning into:

```
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN 0 and 0
```

These being integers, SQL Server attempts to convert `[Date]` to an integer for the comparison -- hence the error.  Unfortunately (well it is not that unfortunate), the simple fix of:

```
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '03/09/2014' AND '04/09/2014'
```

provides only a little relief.  It does happen to work in this case, because the dates are in the same month.  But it won't work in the general case, because these are compared as **strings**:

```
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '03/09/2014' and '01/10/2014'
```

Is probably not going to do what you expect.

You have made a fundamental blunder by storing dates as strings in the database.  Use the correct type (in this case, `date` or `datetime` should be fine).  Then your comparisons will work.  When putting constants into SQL Server, convert them to strings of the form YYYY-MM-DD, because SQL server understands strings in this format.  So, your query could look like this:

```
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2014-09-03' and '2014-09-04'
```

(Or you could use explicit conversion, which in my opinion simply makes queries harder to read.)

How your fellow country-people choose to look at dates is irrelevant.  When you output the dates, use `convert()` to convert to the preferred format.  When you input dates as strings, use `convert()` to convert from the preferred format -- or just let them choose the dates from a calendar tool.  Inside the database, use the format that databases know best -- the built-in date and time types.

Comment: Gordon so your bottom line is that:
i need to send to the SQL server a DateTime (type) and to store it on a field of datetime in the Azure, and to work like an american with the dates ?

Comment: i tried working with the convert from one format to another format of DateTime its never worked...did you worked with convert before ?

Comment: @Ron ... Yes, quite often.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to accomplish this in SQL rather than your code and your date values are guaranteed to be consistently formatted in the manner your example above is, you can use the CONVERT/CAST approach below to get the format that you need.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50),CAST('3/9/2014 21:3' as smalldatetime),103) [DD/MM/YYYY Format]
```

This article on CAST and CONVERT might also be useful to you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx